# How to update vSphere inventory remotely after resizing disk with vmkfstools?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, disk-space-utilization, diskmanagement, vsphere-client

after successfully resized a disk with :

```
vmkfstools --datacenter x --vihost esx42 --server vc1.example.com --username me \
-X 25G -d eagerzeroedthick  /vmfs/volumes/FOOBAR/FOOBAR.vmdk
```

Now, how can I update inventory programmaticaly remotely (not from ESX server), via Linux command line or via any API/script ?

The size did not changed in vSphere 6.0.0 web client even after disconnecting and reconnecting, I need to unregister the VM manually from inventory and re-add it to see the disk changes in vSphere.

The script is a modified version (by myself) because `--datastore` was not really implemented : https://pastebin.com/raw/cE8vFRDe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the VmWare inventory, you need to run :

```
svmotion --datastore foobar --server vc1.example.com --username me \
--password xxx --vm "[DATASTORE_FOO_BAR] vm_name/vm_name.vmx:DATASTORE_DEST"
```